# java apache poi (part 2)

Tags: java, apache-poi

cont. on [java apache poi (part 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735125/java-apache-poi-part-1/28736304#28736304)

- Code

  ```
  ...
  while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
      List<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();

      row = (XSSFRow)rowIterator.next();

      Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

      while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
          cell = cellIterator.next();
          cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

          switch(cell.getCellType()){
              case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                  record.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                  break;
              case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                  record.add(Double.toString
                  (cell.getNumericCellValue()));
              break;
          }
      }
      readFile();
  }

  public void readFile(){
      String ID = record.get(0);
      System.out.println(ID);
  }
  ...
  ```
- From above code, my output is like below:
  ID
  1
  2
  3
- My expected output should like this:
  1
  2
  3
- My question is how to remove the first row from excel (ID) from the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To skip the first row:

```
while(rowIterator.hasNext()){

    row = (XSSFRow)rowIterator.next();

    if(row.getRowNum()==0) {
        continue;
    }

    List<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    ...
    readFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add rowIterator.next(); above the While loop in the program which ignore the first row.So simple.Hope this helps you.

```
 **rowIterator.next();**
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```