# java apache poi (part 3)

Tags: java, swing

cont. on [java apache poi (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755967/java-apache-poi-part-2)

- code

  ```
  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

  list.add("1|Ali");
  list.add("2|Abu");
  list.add("3|Ahmad");

  StringBuilder outputResult = new StringBuilder();

  for(Object staffList: list){
  outputResult.append(staffList.toString());
  outputResult.append("\n");
  }
  ```
- From above code, I try the following: 
  First, I display the output:
   `System.out.println(outputResult.toString());`
     Output: 
  1|Ali
  2|Abu
  3|Ahmad

  Second, I want to put the above output into the label:

  ```
  jLabel1.setText("<HTML>"+outputResult.toString()+"<br /></HTML>");
  ```

  Output:
   1|Ali 2|Abu 3|Ahmad
- My expected output on the label:
  1|Ali
  2|Abu
  3|Ahmad
- My question is how to display the value into the label same as the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't support newline characters, that's the point, that's the way it's designed.

You would need to reformat the output using `<br>` instead...

```
StringBuilder outputResult = new StringBuilder();

for(Object staffList: list){
    outputResult.append(staffList.toString());
    outputResult.append("<br>");
}
```

You could create a helper method which took the line separator that you wanted to use and build the list the way you wanted to...

```
String newLines = buildOutput(list, "/n");
String htmlBR = buildOutput(list, "<br>");
```

Or you could even use an [Unordered list (`<ul>`)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp).

Or you could even use a [HTML table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)